# Searching for a string within a strict format

Tags: python, regex

I want to search for a sub-string using the python re library with the following format:

```
(some word)(\)term1(\)(some word) (some word)(\)term2(\)(some word)
```

The groups in brackets are optional, term1 and term2 must be in the string within that format.

A few examples of what it should detect:

- `random sentence word\term1 term2 end of random sentence`
- `random sentence term1 term2 end of random sentence`
- `random sentence word\term1\word word\term2\word end of random sentence`

so far i have tried this:

```
r'((\W+|^)term1((\W))*)(\w+|) (\w+|)(\W|)term2(\W|)'
```

but it does not work

Comment: what re method were you using to get the match?

Comment: im using re.search

Answer (score 0):

This pattern should work:

```
^[\w ]*\\?term1\\?[\w ]*\\?term2\\?[\w ]*$
```

Python demo:

```
import re

pattern = re.compile(r"^[\w ]*\\?term1\\?[\w ]*\\?term2\\?[\w ]*$")

string1 = r"random sentence word\term1 term2"
string2 = r"random sentence term1 term2 end of random sentence"
string3 = r"random sentence word\term1\word word\term2\word end of random sentence"

print(bool(re.search(pattern, string1)))
print(bool(re.search(pattern, string2)))
print(bool(re.search(pattern, string3)))
```

> Output:
>
> ```
> True
> True
> True
> ```

Comment: I think i didnt phrase the question well, i added examples to clarify

Comment: @DaniyalSelani Yeah you sure didn't :D see my edit, that should do the job :)

Comment: @DaniyalSelani Feel free to also [mark my answer as accepted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/510616) if you feel like it was helpful :)

Answer (score -1):

```
import re

lines = [
    r'random sentence word\term1 term2 end of random sentence',
    r'random sentence term1 term2 end of random sentence',
    r'random sentence word\term1\word word\term2\word end of random sentence'
]

regex = re.compile(r'(\b\w+\b)?\\?term1\\?(\b\w+\b)? (\b\w+\b)?\\?term2\\?(\b\w+\b)?')
for line in lines:
    m = regex.search(line)
    if m:
        print('Match:', m.group(0))
    else:
        print("No match")
```

Prints:

```
Match: word\term1 term2
Match: term1 term2
Match: word\term1\word word\term2\word
```

[image]

Comment: Would whoever downvoted this please explain why they think this is not a solution or why it otherwise falls short. My solution is based upon my reading of the problem, which is not very clear to begin with. for example, I interpret `(some word)` to mean an optional word, which for me translates to `(\bw+\b)?`.